Deployment to Azure Functions fails after importing Python's moviepy
after a few houes of debugging, I have realised that when these lines of code are present, my deployment shows as succeed from VS Code, but the http_trigger doesn't spear in funtion app:
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, AudioFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
from moviepy.video.fx.all import crop


I don't know if that has something to do with ffmpeg binaries, but I have tried to include them in the root directly and specify a path to them with
def get_local_ffmpeg_path():
    """
    Returns the local path to the FFmpeg binary based on the operating system.
    """
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    ffmpeg_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'ffmpeg_bin')
    
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        ffmpeg_path = os.path.join(ffmpeg_dir, 'windows', 'ffmpeg.exe')
    elif platform.system() == "Linux":
        ffmpeg_path = os.path.join(ffmpeg_dir, 'linux', 'ffmpeg')
    else:
        raise OSError("Unsupported operating system. FFmpeg binaries are only provided for Windows and Linux.")
    
    if not os.path.exists(ffmpeg_path):
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"FFmpeg binary not found at {ffmpeg_path}. Please ensure it is included in the deployment package.")
    
    if platform.system() == "Linux":
        os.chmod(ffmpeg_path, os.stat(ffmpeg_path).st_mode | 0o111)  # Adds execute permissions
    
    return ffmpeg_path

def configure_moviepy():
    """
    Configures MoviePy to use the FFmpeg binary from the local deployment package.
    """
    try:
        ffmpeg_path = get_local_ffmpeg_path()
        os.environ["IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE"] = ffmpeg_path
        logging.info(f"Configured MoviePy to use FFmpeg at {ffmpeg_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to configure MoviePy: {e}")
        raise

But that didn't solve the issue. I have also tried to point to a blob storage (this solution works just fine with Azure Web Apps), but that didn't help. As soon as I comment these two lines out, the function loads on Azure:

I have it in requirements.txt:
moviePy==1.0.3
and everything works just fine in VS Code. I would be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Please share the error message.

Hi,there is no error message - from VS Code I get a success, but the http_trigger never appears in the Functions

Can you share your complete function code @JohTok

You should be able to deploy the function successfully using  moviepy v1.0 module to function app.
I have used below code for testing purpose.
import azure.functions as func
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, AudioFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
from moviepy.video.fx import crop
import logging
import os

base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
ffmpeg_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'ffmpeg_bin')

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    logging.info(f"FFmpeg directory set to: {ffmpeg_dir}")

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

I have below modules in requirements.txt file.
azure-functions
moviepy==1.0.3

I am able to deploy successfully to Azure function app.


